# dlsym' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I started doing cross compile following this steps:

```
At step 10 after doing the configuration with this command:


I run the make command and revice the following errors:


Any Ideas about solving this?


https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS
```

Configure command: 
       ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -v -no-use-gold-linker

```
make command result: 
       /home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/qtbase/lib/libQt5EglSupport.a(qeglplatformcontext.o): In function QEGLPlatformContext::getProcAddress(char const*)': qeglplatformcontext.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference todlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [Makefile.eglfsdeviceintegration:252: ../../../../lib/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5.12.5] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:46: sub-eglfsdeviceintegration-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:102: sub-eglfs-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:78: sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/qtbase/src/plugins'

    make[1]: *** [Makefile:832: sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mihai/Desktop/raspi/qtbase/src'
make: *** [Makefile:51: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

Comment: I started doing this steps and at step 10 after configure command, I run make command and revice those errors, any idea of solving this?

Comment: You can edit your question to add details, don't post a comment for this.